# Drop-Down-Menu for Many-to-Many relation in rails using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I have three tables via many-to-many-association: Supermarket, Product and Supply.
Each Supermarket can hold many products and each product can be sold in many supermarkets. The association is build via the Supply-model.

Supermarket:

```
class Supermarket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :address, :products_attributes

  has_many :supplies
  has_many :products, :through => :supplies

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products
end
```

Product:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :supermarkets_attributes

  has_many :supplies
  has_many :supermarkets, :through => :supplies
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :supermarkets
end
```

Association via Supply:

```
class Supply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :supermarket_id, :product_id

  belongs_to :supermarket
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I have created the scaffolds and populated the Supermarket-table.
In my Product form, i want to use one (or more) drop-down-menu(s) to select the correspondent Supermarket-name(s). Goal is to create a new product while also creating the association via the Supply-table.
What should the code look like in form and/or controller for the products if I want to select the corresponding supermarkets from there?

Comment: So I can solve this via the `collection_select`-helper and it works just fine. But as being relatively new to rails, I want to know: what is the difference to using `nested forms` as described in [Railscast #196](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) - i.e. what are the (dis)advantages of using what and where do I use what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you products form you need to add this line...

```
<%= collection_select(:product, :supermarket_ids, SuperMarket.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => true } )%>
```

You also shouldn't need to use an accepts_nested_attributes for this, the many to many association you already have set up should take care of the rest.

Comment: That looks very promising: the form shows up, but when sending it I get an `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error` Another sulution I tried is to use a `fields_for` but I got the same error.

Comment: I came across something similar(I used this approach for skills and users).  Try adding :supermarket_id to your attr_accessible list in products.

Comment: Okay, that did the trick :-). I had some apprehension about security when adding it to the model, because the mass-assignment security-warning is certainly there for a reason - but skimming through [the mass-assignment rails-guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) I think it's not more a risk than nested forms too. Probably someone here can give me further information...

Answer (score 0):

I think in views

`<%= f.collection_select "super_market_ids[]",@super_markets,:id,:name,{},{:multiple=>"multiple'} %>`

I am not sure about `super_market_ids` or `super_market_ids[]` and syntax just verified once.

In select tag if you want checkbox type multi select there is an [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) library that will help you to build nicer UI,

Comment: OK, I think collection_select is the way to go - but i want to access the **supermarkets** from the **products**-form. What variables do I have to use?

Comment: in controller in products action edit and new `@super_markets = SuperMarket.all`

Comment: Sorry, it does not work - is super_market_ids something that rails does automagically?

Comment: to be precise: i get a `NoMethodError` for any combination of `super_market_id` or `super_markets_id` or so on...

Comment: watch this epidode it's similar http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes?view=asciicast