# Form to create entries in many-to-many relationship with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, database-design, many-to-many, has-many-through

My application consists of these five models:
A *supermarket* can have different *categories* of products and the products in these *categories* can be produced by several *brands*.

Now I want to have one (or two) **Selection**-field(s) in my *supermarket*-form in which I can select one element in *Category* with its name appearing and one or more element(s) in *Brand* with its name appearing, so this could be stored in *Origin*.

I think I could use `collection_select`, but how do I utilize it here?

```
class Supermarket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :supplies
  has_many :origins, :through => :supplies
end

class Supply < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :origin  
  belongs_to :supermarket  
end

class Origin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :origins
end

class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :origins
end
```

Probably, I also have to tweak the models...

---

**Edit**

To clarify what the outcome of the form should be:

In the form to edit *Supermarkets* I want to select a *Category* of products and the corresponding *Brands* so that I know, which *Category* and which *Brands* in this *Category* is/are sold in this specific *Supermarket*:

#### Supermarket (Form):

Name of **Supermarket**: *Walmart*

---

**Category** (Select one):

- Cola *(Category_ID 1)*
- Cornflakes *(Category_ID 2)*
- ...

---

**Brand** (multiple Select)

- The Coca-Cola Company *(Brand_ID 1)*
- PepsiCo *(Brand_ID 2)*
- Kellogg Company *(Brand_ID 3)*
- ...

This should create entries in **Origin** like:

```
Supermarket_ID Category_ID Brand_ID 
      1            1          1 
      1            1          2 
      2            1          2 
      2            2          3 
     ...          ...        ...
```

**/Edit**

---

**Edit 2**

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445675/many-to-many-to-many-relationship-with-need-for-another-specific-model), I could create or select an entry *via console* like this:

```
walmart = Supermarket.create(:name => "Walmart");
cornflakes = Category.create(:name => "Corn Flakes");
kellogs = Brand.create(:name => "Kellog's");

walmart.origins.create(:category_id => cornflakes, :brand_id = kellogs)
```

How can I make use of this via a **form**? How could I utilize `select` or `collection_select` or is there even another helper I could use?

**/Edit 2**

Answer (score 0):

I have also had a similar problem when utilizing many-to-many relationships. One worthwhile gem to check out would be [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

They have a nice form helper for to_many associations.

In terms of actually implementing the form, I'm not sure I understood how the form data will be used. Regardless, javascript and virtual attributes are your friends here.

**EDIT:**

Ah, I see what you're saying. the way I would do this would be to create one select_field, for selecting the category, then I would create another select_field (setting :multiple => true) so I can select multiple brands.

```
<%= select_tag "supermarket[supplies][][category]" ... %>
<%= select_tag "supermarket[supplies][][brands]", ... %> <!-- be sure to set multiple to true !-->
```

Next, you need to associate everything together. So for that, I would create a virtual attribute that handles the form submission. For example:

```
def supplies=(supplies_hash)
# read supplies_hash and create the active records. 
end

def supplies

end
```

Finally, if you're insisting on doing this without a gem, I recommend you take a look at the [nested form railscast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) to get an idea of what's involved.

Comment: I see, but there must be a way without additional gems... Should be a common problem. Furthermore my goal is to understand how to work with relationships and entering data in the correct table...

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's worthwhile to learn what's involved in implementing this without gems. However, once you do it once, you'll likely want to use the gems to save time. 

What you are doing in this form is nesting a number of active record models. You'll have a much easier time if you spread this functionality to a separate form after you create the supermarket. Doing so would allow you not to nest any models and have an easier time.

Comment: You mean I should create a form where I would have 3 select fields? For `Supermarket`, `Category` and `Brand`? I have watched the Nested Forms-Railscast several times before, but I did not figure out how to apply it to this situation where there is a has_many "chaining".

Comment: Furthermore I don't understand what a select field's return value is & how I would work with it in the controller. Without a form I could create a new entry in origins like `walmart = Supermarket.create(:name => "Walmart");` `cornflakes = Category.create(:name => "Corn Flakes");`
`kellogs = Brand.create(:name => "Kellog's");`
`walmart.origins.create(:category_id => cornflakes, :brand_id = kellogs)` like in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445675/many-to-many-to-many-relationship-with-need-for-another-specific-model) (thanks @marlin-pierce).